Android API 31 onwards --> EncoderProfiles.getAll unresolved
This is driving me crazy for daays.
I imported all correct and still get "getAll" unresolved error on Android even so set all correct in the "build.gradle.kts"
android {
    namespace = "com.example.myapplication"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk = 26
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = code
        versionName = "1.0"
    }

    // ...
}

Everything works so far with CamcorderProfile, but I get always an error that it is deprecated from 33 onwards...
Documentation of CamrecorderProfile:
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/media/CamcorderProfile#getAll(kotlin.String,%20kotlin.Int)
It says to get all encoder back just use EncoderProfiles.getAll(cameraId, it)
There is even a ? behind, do not know why in case I go to EncoderProfiles (https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/media/EncoderProfiles) there is no such getAll...
How can I solve this?
My code below.
import android.media.EncoderProfiles

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
fun getAvailableEncoderProfiles(cameraManager: CameraManager, cameraId: String): List<Int> {
    val characteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId)
    val cameraDirection = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING)

    if (cameraDirection == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT) {
        // Front-facing camera, return only QUALITY_HIGH
        return listOf(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH).also {
            Log.d("CameraApp", "Front-facing camera detected, using QUALITY_HIGH")
        }
    }

    val qualities = listOf(
        CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_8KUHD,
        CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_4KDCI,
        CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_2160P,
        CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_1080P,
        CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_2K,
        CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_720P,
        CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P,
        CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_CIF,
        CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_QVGA,
        CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_QCIF,
        CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW,
        CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH,
    )

    val availableQualities = qualities.filter {
        try {
            EncoderProfiles.getAll(cameraId, it) != null
        } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
            false
        }
    }

    availableQualities.forEach { quality ->
        Log.d("CameraApp", "EncoderProfiles available for quality: $quality")
    }

    return availableQualities
}

getAll working as documented by Android

The getAll method is a class method from CamcorderProfile, not EncoderProfiles. It returns EncoderProfiles though.
This should fix the problem:
CamcorderProfile.getAll(cameraId, it) != null

